# MSBuild pack: How to include certain file types to be copied to output?

Tags: msbuild, nuget-package

In my .csproj file, I defined the following ItemGroup:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\VectorDraw\VectorDraw Developer Framework 10.1002.0.1\bin\VectorDraw.Generics.dll" PackageCopyToOutput="true">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\lib\net6.0-windows7.0\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\VectorDraw\VectorDraw Developer Framework 10.1002.0.1\bin\VectorDraw.Professional.dll" PackageCopyToOutput="true">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\lib\net6.0-windows7.0\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="..\..\..\..\Program Files (x86)\VectorDraw\VectorDraw Developer Framework 10.1002.0.1\bin\VectorDraw.Serialize.dll" PackageCopyToOutput="true">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\lib\net6.0-windows7.0\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

These DLLs above are packed as expected and then when the nuget package is installed, the DLLs appear in the output directory. Now, the following file needs to be packed and copied to the output folder as well:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="$(TargetDir)\VdsConverter.dll.vdlic" PackageCopyToOutput="true">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>\lib\net6.0-windows7.0\</PackagePath>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

After executing the pack command, all the files are copied to the lib folder in the package including my license file.
But when I install the nuget package in a project, the license file is not copied while the other DLLs are copied. So, I suppose that certain file types are prevented from being copied to the output folder. How can I include these files?